# How to match layer shapes Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to replicate this model in Tensorflow (I have to use Tensorflow, not Pytorch), the only infos are these:

| Layer | Out channels | Kernel size | Stride |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AdaptAvgPool3D | 8 | - | - |
| Conv2D | 32 | (1,1) | (1,1) |

The model I created following the scheme above is :

```
from keras import layers
def make_model():
  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(layers.GlobalAveragePooling3D())
  model.add(layers.Conv2D(32,(1,1),strides=(1, 1)))
  return model
```

My input shape is (585854, 3), so I am trying to create a noise tensor with the same shape to feed this model.
`noise = tf.random.normal(input.shape[0], input.shape[1])`
As GlobalAveragePooling3D requires a 5D input, here was my updated code

```
output_channels = 8 #specified in the paper
noise = tf.random.normal((input.shape[0],1,1,1,output_channels))
projection_model = make_model()
projection = projection_model(noise)
```

It successfully passes the pooling layer, but at the convolution layer throws an error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-b224bcb040fd> in <cell line: 8>()
      7 projection_model = make_model()
----> 8 projection = projection_model(noise)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    251             ndim = x.shape.rank
    252             if ndim is not None and ndim < spec.min_ndim:
--> 253                 raise ValueError(
    254                     f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '
    255                     "is incompatible with the layer: "

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_3' (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "conv2d_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (585854, 8)

Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_3' (type Sequential):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(585854, 1, 1, 1, 8), dtype=float32)
  • training=None
  • mask=None
```

My questions are

1. what size should my random noise tensor be in order not to throw error?
2. Did I set any parameter wrong?
   Many thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @currymobile, Why are you using GlobalAveragePooling3D when there are GlobalAveragePooling2D and GlobalAveragePooling1D also available? What is your dataset type and requirement? Can you please share minimal reproducible code to understand the issue and assist you better? Thank you.